# Custom firefox profiles with different WM_CLASS and icons

Tags: firefox, gnome, shortcuts, window-manager, kiosk

So I have different firefox profiles that I launch in kiosk mode in order to have small apps for Youtube and Netflix. I saw this problem asked multiple times but I tried other answers and it still doesn't work.

I use a `youtube.desktop` file that launches firefox with a custom `WM_CLASS`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Youtube
Comment=Launch Youtube in kiosk mode
Type=Application

Exec=firefox --no-remote --new-instance -P "kiosk-youtube" --kiosk --class Firefox-kiosk-youtube https://youtube.com
Terminal=false

Icon=/home/user/.local/share/icons/kiosk-firefox-icons/youtube.png
StartupWMClass=Firefox-kiosk-youtube
```

Different Firefox profiles are still grouped together and using the basic firefox icon.
I'm on GNOME, Ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Update (2023-07-07)**: Removing the `-no-remote` CLI option avoids the *Firefox is already running, but is not responding* error.

For me (using Wayland and Gnome 43 on Fedora 37), the catch was to use `--name Firefox-kiosk-youtube` instead of `--class Firefox-kiosk-youtube`.

To have GNOME Shell show a nice icon and the contents of `Name` rather than `WM_CLASS` (or `wmclass`) directly, you also need to set `StartupWMClass` to the same value (e.g. `Firefox-kiosk-youtube`).

Here is my complete `firefox-personal.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox (Personal)
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Browse the Web
Exec=firefox -P personal --name FirefoxPersonal %u
Icon=firefox
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;text/mml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupNotify=true
# NOTE: If this is not set to the same as the argument of the --name option,
# then GNOME Shell won't show the nice Firefox icon and the user facing
# "Firefox (Personal)" text along with it.
StartupWMClass=FirefoxPersonal
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
Keywords=web;browser;internet;
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;profile-manager-window;

X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.26

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=firefox -P personal --name FirefoxPersonal --new-window %u

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=firefox -P personal --name FirefoxPersonal --private-window %u
```

To verify the `WM_CLASS` value, one can use GNOME Shell's built-in tool [Looking Glass](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/LookingGlass).

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `lg` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the top-right panel, select "Windows".

The `WM_CLASS` will be displayed under the `wmclass` key.

For example:
[image]